# Whether we can use WPF in .NET 2.0?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

If it is possible, pls explain me how we can implement WPF in .NET 2.0 with C#. Thanks..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, you can't. The difference between .NET 2.0 and 3.0 basically *is* the libraries - WPF, WCF, CardSpace and Workflow Foundation.

If at all possible, update to a much more recent version of .NET - ideally 4.0, but 3.5SP1 would also be better than just 3.0.

EDIT: As per 0xA3's comments, I should clarify that there are additional services in .NET 3.0. However, .NET 3.0 doesn't change any of the existing libraries or types, it doesn't change the CLR, and it doesn't have any supporting language features.

Comment: I have always wondered about these questions Jon.
There are security and performance improvements such as the updated CLR.

Comment: It maybe should be added that .NET 3.0 - and in particular WPF - is not simply an addition of libraries. It also brings additional configuration settings and services such as the WPF Font Cache service.

Answer (score 3):

You can't use WPF in .NET 2.0, that's one of the main differences between 2.0 and 3.0.

My advice would be to update to the latest version of .NET if at all possible, .NET 4.0. Obviously you can use the WPF with this version.

Answer (score 0):

It is not at all possible to use wpc and wcf using 2.0 If you want to use those concepts then you need to upgrade your dot net version to 4.0 so that you can use all facilities of .net

Answer (score 0):

It may be worth pointing out that WPF and the other assemblies making up .NET 3.0 CAN be referenced and used by C# 2.0 projects. Some .NET shops require C# code to be compilable by earlier versions of Visual Studio, even though higher versions of .NET may be installed. I'm wondering if the original poster is in that situation.

Of course, for those assemblies to be present, at least .NET 3.0 must be installed.